# VideoView can not play video

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, mp4

```
final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
videoView.setVideoPath("/edited_For Render - 1280x720.mp4");
videoView.start();
```

i'm trying to play a video in my app, but when i run it on my nexus 4 it says that the video can not be played. the video is placed in the res folder of the project in android-studio and it's an mp4 with H.264 codec.

Comment: where is you file stored?

Comment: "the video is placed in the res folder of the project in android-studio"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved it.

the problem was the video path. it has to be

```
videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.trailer);
```

(i also had to rename the file to trailer.mp4 because android can't handle spaces in filenames and i moved it to the raw folder)

Answer (score 0):

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video1);
    videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.m);// check your path
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.start();
```